# Python: SMTP credentials are correct but authentication fails

Tags: python, powershell, authentication, smtp

I'm attempting to send an email with a Python script that I've converted from a functioning PowerShell script. When it tries to run with Python the credentials fail, but when it runs with PowerShell they work and I can't figure out why.

[Error that I'm getting when it runs through Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un4TA.png)

This is the Python script

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(send_from, to_email, email_body)
```

This is the PowerShell script

```
$SendFrom="email@example.com"
$sendMailParams = @{
    From = $SendFrom
    To = $toEmail
    cc = $ccEmail
    bcc =  "email@example.com"
    Subject = "$subject"
    Body = "$hyperlink"
    SMTPServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    #Port = 587
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential = $credential
    Attachments = $filename
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailParams -WarningAction Continue
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(...) as server:` and then remove `$server.starttls()` (SMTP over TLS instead of STARTTLS over SMTP)

Comment: I end up with a "Wrong Version number (_ssl.c:1000) error

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)